# Save RTSP stream with Netty

Tags: java, netty, rtsp, rtsp-client

I need to save / capture locally some audio/video stream available via RTSP.
Searched for some solution and understand that there is Netty support for such.

Can somebody provide a quick example ?

Comment: FFmpeg is the better solution.

Comment: Need to do that programmatically, from Java

Comment: i suggest reading the netty documentation and then having a look at the `org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.rtsp` package

Comment: @JonasAdler, Could you please provide me with some very very basic sample code ? I could not find some working code for such use-case and I am a beginner with Netty.